Non-semisimple Lie group
Consider the non-semisimple Lie group $\mathsf{SO}_0(n+1, n) \ltimes \mathbb R^{2n+1}$. I think dimension of the group is $n$. Is the group reductive with semisimple part Hermitian?

The dimension of this group is far from $n$. I think it is $n(2n+1) + 2n+1 = 2n^2+3n+1 $. The group is also not reductive as, while it is the product of semisimple group and an abelian one, the abelian group is not its centre. I'm not sure what you mean by Hermitian but I guess you might be asking if it is contained in some $SU(N)$ (which, for a semisimple group, amounts to asking if it is compact). In which case the answer there is also no.

Thanks for your answer.  I have one more question. Is the group simple?

@Ein It isn't even semisimple so it cannot be simple

Then which kind of group is this? Just asking for my knowledge.

@Ein It might be a perfect non-semisimple group, arising in a geometric context. You should give some more context in your question, where it comes from, and why you are looking for it, why you suggest it should be reductive, and what algebraic properties you want to consider.

@Ein I think your question presumes that it has to fit into some neat type. For example, we often study semisimple and solvable Lie groups but most Lie groups are neither.
